# Linebreak in delete alert

Tags: javascript, cakephp, alert

I got a delete link in an index view:

```
$alertText = 'Want to delete %s?\n 2nd line';
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Löschen'), array(
   'action' => 'delete', $event['Event']['id']), null,
    __($alertText, $event['Event']['id']));
```

Now I want to have an alert with two lines,
so I tried the following, but it is not working.

```
\n
\\\n
```

Do you have an Idea why the default behavior for new lines is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with double quotes

```
$alertText = "Want to delete %s?\n 2nd line";
```

Comment: this is really strange, thx so much I was loosing my mind about this.